# Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that $x ≡ 3$ (mod $9$) and y ≡$ 4$ (mod $9$). Is it possible that $ 20x + 3y^3 ≡ 6$ (mod $9$)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have problem answering this question. I know the answer is not possible but I by simply substitute the 3 and 4 but I have clue why so. Can anyone give me an explanation or a correct way to answer this question properly.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you mean $3y^3$?

Comment: Yeah...just corrected it

Comment: Such substitution is valid by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), an inductive extension of the Sum and Product Rules.

Comment: Yes, substitution works.  Prove that if $a\equiv a' \pmod N$ and $b \equiv b' \pmod N$ then $a+b \equiv a' + b'\pmod N$ and $ab \equiv a'b' \pmod N$ and the $a^k \equiv a'^k \pmod N$.  Those rules imply if $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial with two variable then $P(a,b) \equiv P(a',b')$. ... to prove those rules you have $a = jN +a'$ and $b= kN+b'$ and however you manipulate those only manipulations directly relating to $a'$ and $b'$ won't be multiplied byt a multiple of $N$....

Comment: Example $a=jN + a'$ and $b = kN + b'$ means $a+b = (j+k)N + (a'+b')$ and $ab = N(jkN + j+ k) + (a'b')$ and $(jN + a')^k =$... a bunch of terms involving $N$ to powers .... $+ a'^k$.

Comment: It's good practice to work it out *once* for yourself.  If $x = 9*j + 3$ and $y = 9k+4$ then $20x + 3y^3 = 20(9j + 3) + 3(9k + 4) = 20*9j + 2([9k]^3 + 3*4*[9k]^2 + 3*4^2*9k) + 20*3 + 3*4^3$ and the only things that *aren't* a multiple of $9$ are the $20*3 + 3*4^3$.  I.e. a substitution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, because if $x\equiv3\pmod9$ and $y\equiv4\pmod9$,

then $20x+3y^3\equiv20\times3+3\times4^3\equiv60+3\times1\equiv0\pmod9$.

Comment: congruences are compatible with polynomial evaluation